# Opening Podfile in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ide, cocoapods

Such a trivial concern should show up first on google, but the answer isn't on SO.

I am tired of using vim when Xcode is supposed to be an IDE (emphasis on I)

How do I open a Podfile in Xcode?

Answer (score 9):

you can open with Xcode just get into your directory on the terminal and then just type

```
open -a Xcode <podfile>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `Podfile` is located in the root of the Pods project.

[image]

An easy way to open it is via "Open Quickly" (Shift Cmd O) typing Podfile.

Comment: won't be there any issues if podfile/podspec is added into xcode project? As I can see Xcode adds it to resources - so it would end up inside application bundle

Comment: Note that this "Pods" project might not show if you haven't already run `pod install` before opening a project's `.xcworkspace` file. If there's no `Pods` top-level entry alongside (not inside) your app, 1) run `pod install`, 2) check it's the `.xcworkspace` file you opened and not the app's `.xcodeproj`

Answer (score 0):

If it's been added to the project, you can just click on it. Otherwise, open it using the File menu or drag its icon on top of Xcode's.